# Nested JSON from AWS Lambda in Angular

Tags: json, angularjs

I am using the following to consume RESTful API info into AngularJS:

```
angular.module('demo', [])
.controller('Hello', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('restapi address').
        then(function(response) {
            $scope.content = response.data;
            console.log(response)
        });
});
```

and I'm using the response data in my index as follows (this part isn't working, see below):

```
<div ng-controller="Hello">
        <p>The ID is {{content.course-content}}</p>
        <p>The content is {{content.course-id}}</p>
        <p>The content is {{content.course-title}}</p>
</div>
```

and here is the JSON response from the API call:

```
{
    "body": [{
        "course-content": "In order for you to be successful in the program",
        "course-id": "supervised-ml",
        "course-title": "Supervised ML"
    }]
}
```

How can I display course-content, course-id, and course title? I know these are nested, but am unsure how to reference each item within the controller for rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a minor correction to the interpolations within your HTML should do it:

```
<div ng-controller="Hello">
    <p>The ID is {{content['course-content']}}</p>
    <p>The content is {{content['course-id']}}</p>
    <p>The content is {{content['course-title']}}</p>
</div>
```

The hyphens in your property names need to be enclosed in string literals to ensure they reference properly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the revisions didn't work (same issue).

Comment: Ah, I missed something—is the JSON response snippet you included the value of `response.data` you're assigning to `$scope.content`? If it is, then you'll have to unpack that first item (e.g. `$scope.content = response.data.body[0]`).